# how to download data to a folder from database in codeigniter automatically

Tags: codeigniter

I am working on a project using Codeigniter where i need to download a list of data from database automatically every 24 hours to a folder in the form of excel sheet ?

Answer (score 0):

1.get data list form database
2. save to a file in folder
3.then sent by email/download it.

[How to write data into .txt file in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31072419/how-to-write-data-into-txt-file-in-codeigniter)

Comment: yes this is what i exactly need but i m not getting what to write in MVC .I am new to codeigniter . If possible please guide me with example .thank you.